# Forcing numbered bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, acm

I'm using the [acmsmall.cls](http://www.acm.org/publications/latex_style/) document class. My issue is in that my reference list is coming up unnumbered, yet my `\cite{}` tags are producing (correctly indexed) number based references. (e.g. `[1]`)

How can I either force my reference list to be numbered, or automate my citations to contain author information, or something else which can be linked to my reference list, without the user needing to count along! (I'm not restricted in my reference formatting, but how it is now obviously doesn't work!)

I'm currently formatting my bibliography like so.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem{G}
Carretero, J., Isaila, F., Kermarrec, A. M., Taïani, F., \& Tirado, J. M. 
(2012, June). 
Geology: Modular georecommendation in gossip-based social networks. 
In Distributed Computing Systems (ICDCS), 2012 IEEE 32nd International Conference on (pp. 637-646). 
IEEE.

\end{thebibliography}
```

I've tried to make use of `\citeA{key}` and `\citeN{key}` suggested in the acmclass comments, but with no success - I don't know if these need a Bibtex file to work? I've also tried various `\begin{thebibliography}` with various second parameters, with no luck.

Comment: Did you try `\begin{thebibliography}{99}` instead of `\begin{thebibliography}{}`?

Comment: Yes - no difference. (Sorry, forgot to include that!)

Comment: The original source is [ACM LaTeX Style Guide](http://www.acm.org/publications/latex_style/). And you can edit your own questions (and answers) also with low reputation.

Comment: Indeed - but I thought I'd link to a site where people can view the class without having to download. (Should I change it?)

Comment: @Chris: Without looking deeper I see, that the ACM site does provide version 2, while the university site does provide version 1.1. Working with old versions is off-topic here when this is the cause for the issue. And ***I*** would in general favour to link to the original source as long as possible.

Comment: Thank you @Speravir - I will test with the newer version, and update the question later tonight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Versions 1.1 and 1.4 of the class file `acmsmall.cls` -- the versions linked to in your posting and in @speravir's comment, respectively -- seem to be identical with respect to the formatting of the bibliography. Hence, the following code should work with either version of the `acmsmall` class file. (Aside: the website says all file versions are "2", but when you download and open the file `acmsmall.cls` it says that the version is 1.4.)

Relative to the "standard" LaTeX document classes (i.e., `article`, `book`, and `report`), the `acmsmall` class simplifies the internal list environment used by the `thebibliography` environment; the most important simplification consists of *not* showing numeric labels. It would appear to be the case that one is supposed to use an *author-year* citation style with the `acmsmall` class; with such a citation style, providing numeric labels indeed serves no practical purpose.

You seem to be building the references "by hand", i.e., by providing various `\bibitem`s, and you seem to be interested in using a numeric citation style. In order to use a numeric labeling system while still using the `acmsmall` class file, you should insert the code given in the preamble of the example below -- from `\makeatletter` to `\makeatother` -- in your document's preamble. (Aside: The example below uses version 1.4 of `acmsmall`; I haven't tried it out with the older version, 1.1.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{acmsmall}
\makeatletter
\def\@biblabel#1{[#1]} % restore basic form of \@biblabel macro
\def\thebibliography#1{%
    \footnotesize
    \refsection*{{\refname}
        \@mkboth{\uppercase{\refname}}{\uppercase{\refname}}%
    }
    \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}% %the default form of first arg is {}
       {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
        \leftmargin\labelwidth
        \advance\leftmargin\bibindent
        \itemindent-\bibindent
        \itemsep2pt
        \parsep \z@
        \usecounter{enumiv}% % default is to use enumi
        \let\p@enumiv\@empty
        \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}%
    }%
    \let\newblock\@empty
    \sloppy
    \sfcode`\.=1000\relax
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\cite{G}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{G} Carretero, J., Isaila, F., Kermarrec, A. M., Taïani, F., \& Tirado, J. M. (2012, June). Geology: Modular georecommendation in gossip-based social networks. In Distributed Computing Systems (ICDCS), 2012 IEEE 32nd International Conference on (pp. 637-646). IEEE.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect solution and explanation - thank you!